# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to push `data` attribute value into array parameter but it throws the above error on the line  **parameter[parent].push(parent);**

```
var parameter = {};

var currentTabSelected = "";
var parent = "";

$("#categories").on("click", ":checkbox", function () {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        parent = $(this).data("parent");
        console.log(parent)

        if (!(currentTabSelected  in parameter)) {
            parameter[currentTabSelected] = []
        }

        var found = $.inArray($(this).val(), parameter[currentTabSelected]) > -1;

        if (!found) {
            parameter[currentTabSelected].push($(this).val());
            parameter[parent].push(parent);
            console.log(parameter)
        }
    } else {
        var index = parameter[currentTabSelected].indexOf($(this).val());
        var parent_index = parameter[parent].indexOf(parent)

        if (index > -1) {
            parameter[currentTabSelected].splice(index, 1);
            parameter[parent].splice(parent_index , 1);
        }
    }
})
```

what can i do to overcome the above problem?

Comment: Where is `parameter` array defined?

Comment: where is parameter defined ?

Comment: Side note: There's no need whatsoever for the inner `()` here: `if (!(found)){` Just `if (!found)` is semantically identical and more typical.

Comment: parameter[currentTabSelected]=[] is an array, but parameter[paernt] its not, then you get the exception

Comment: edited to include the arrray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If parameter is an *object* you should create keys before using them.
You are trying to access the key which is *not present* in the parameter.

For example , make sure your object *contains* `currentTabSelected` and `parent`:

```
parameter[currentTabSelected] = []
parameter[parent] = []
```

After initializing `currentTabSelected` and `parent` you can perform operation on  `parameter[currentTabSelected]`,   `parameter[parent]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot got it resloved P2

Comment: Random *italics* aren't *much* better. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I suffered from the same issue few days ago, the solution is directly related with the 'this' keyword. Your 'this' is referring to another scope that your variable is not a part of. You might want to do a

```
var that=this;
```

Or if you're comfortable with ES6, you can use the arrow function syntax.

Comment: No, they're using `this` correctly. It's set by jQuery to refer to the element the `click` event is hooked on.